# Problem with SSI includes, PHP file_get_contents() and https

Tags: php, https, file-get-contents, server-side-includes, ssi

I have a script that pulls a file's contents and then echos it out like so:

```
$file_to_read = "http://website.com/" . $file_name;
$text = @file_get_contents($file_to_read);
echo $text;
```

This is the way I've done it, because the files getting read have SSI includes and once echoed would not work.

Now I need to replicate the code but call the same website with https and it's not working. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do the same thing, but have it work while calling an https URL or using a local path?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the https-version of the site doesn't have SSI enabled? Even though it's the "same" side, most webservers require completely different configuration defintions for SSL and non-SSL sites.

Comment: Marc - The https-version does have SSI enabled as it works in other parts of the https site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had more luck with using cURL as opposed to file_get_contents, here is what I use for my facebook api calls that include an access_token (only available on secure connections):

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$file_to_read);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$text = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Comment: Curl isn't an option for me at this time. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure to what website (or service) you are trying to connect, but I always try to just remove the 's' in 'https' and see if it still works; I know I've been surprised before.